# How to deploy app in ios simulator(Xcode 6.0.1)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have istalled Xcode 6.0.1 in my Mac machine and i have an application with name `203327FE-CFEC-4333-AEA3-EF030B303BAB`. Earlier in iOS 7 simulator i used to copy this folder inside `~/Library/Application Support/iOS Simulator/7.0/Applications/` and when i start the iOS Simulator i can see my app in the simulator. But after updating to XCODE 6 i am not able to find 8.0 folder inside the above simulator folder.

How can i install my custom app on new simulator?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", [NSBundle mainBundle]); will give location of your app.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Xcode's 'Build & Run' feature to install and run your app.  If that is not an option available to you, you can bundle your app yourself and use simctl (new in Xcode 6.0) to install your app.  Example:

```
xcrun simctl list # get the UDID
xcrun simctl install [Device UDID] /path/to/MyGame.app
xcrun simctl launch [Device UDID] com.mycompany.mygame
```

If you have a newer version of Xcode, you can use the special token "booted" in place of the UDID to install/launch using the currently booted device.

Comment: i used this command to install my app on Simulator xcrun simctl install booted <location of .app file>. but when i try to open the app from simulator. It is not getting opened..

Comment: is your app crashing?  Look in the device's syslog and look for a crash report.